# query_posts and custom taxonomy posts order

Tags: custom-taxonomy, query-posts, sort

i have a custom taxonomy defined for "Projects" and a page that shows all the projects. In this page there's a jquery filtering menu (isotope). Initially the page must show all the projects but chronologically ('chronological' is a category and 1970, 1980, 1990, etc are subcats for a Projects element) ordered in DESC mode.

Now the query that initially shows the Projects in the page is

```
query_posts('post_type=portfolio&project-type='.get_post_meta($post->ID, 'portfolio_page_cats', true).'&posts_per_page=-1&orderby=menu_order&order=ASC');
```

There are a lot of questions about this argument, i know. Please, what is the best way to do that?

Regards,

Comment: Just so I'm clear, 'Projects' is a taxonomy with a slug of 'project-type', containing a term 'chronological', and 'chronological' contains sub-terms corresponding to numeric dates (and you want to sort by those sub-terms)?

Comment: Yes, it's correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to order your posts by taxonomy terms, it's not technically possible in one query (since multiple terms can belong to multiple posts - which means that WordPress *cannot* support 'orderby' for taxonomies or terms because there are potentially more than one).

Your solution would be:

1. [Fetch a list of your (sub)terms](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms) and loop through them.
2. In each term loop, run [query_posts()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts) to fetch only posts attached to the current term.
3. In each term loop (after the query), create your content-output loop to display your posts.